# How to read 'an extra' from an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

i've been hooking on to an event (with a BroacastReceiver) and from the docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) i should get a specific object 'as an extra':

`The NetworkInfo for the affected network is sent as an extra`

and

`the NetworkInfo for the new network is also passed as an extra.`

My question is: in my broadcastreceiver i have this event that fires:

`public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {`

and as i understand I should be able to get those two 'extras' out of the intent?

How can I do that?

I tried inspecting the `intent` object in Eclipse in debug mode on mouseover (I am quite new in Eclipse, so i don't know any other way to inspect a variable at runtime) but that didn't give me much info....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     int i = intent.getExtras().getInt("keyName");
     String s = intent.getExtras().getString("keyName");

...
```

Comment: The key for the NetworkInfo should be `ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO`

Comment: How can i get an object of the type `NetworkInfo`, as there is no `getNetworkInfo()`?

Comment: you can't pass any type of object you want in an intent, it's restricted to Strings Doubles Integers ..., not your types

Comment: @Michel `(NetworkInfo)intent.getExtras().get("ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO")`

Comment: Yeah! that did the trick, thanks very much @Day. Despite the -1 voters for the questions, i am very happy with the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    int id = intent.getExtra.getInt("id");
    String name = intent.getExtra.getString("name");

   .......
}
```

You can get *any datatype of extra from intent*. For the list of datatypes that can be retrieved using intent, visit [INTENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type ofthe data you want to retrieve from the intent. For example, if it's an `int` or `boolean` you use:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
int exampleInt = extras.getInt('Name of the extra corresponding to that variable');
boolean exampleBoolean = extras.getBoolean('Name of this other extra');
```